# How can I return unique values horizontally on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique, horizontallist

I have a table that looks like this from A1-A10

```
**Animal**
Zebra
Zebra
Zebra
Giraffe
Giraffe
Monkey
Monkey
Cat
Cat
```

I want to return ONLY the unique values HORIZONTALLY in a row - and have them sorted alphabetically

like this:

```
Cat   Giraffe   Monkey   Zebra
```

Currently I have this formula in D3: but this returns unique values vertically

=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/(COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $A$2:$A$10)=0), $A$2:$A$10), "")

```
Zebra
Monkey
Giraffe
Cat
```

Comment: Does it have to be a formula?

Comment: @sophods only because if the data within the range A1-A10 changes I want this to be reflected on the horizontal data - is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Microsoft365:

```
=TOROW(SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A10)))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this without the transpose function - I tried using this and excel keeps adding {  } in front of the formula when I upload the file which means someone has to manually enter the cell for the formula to work

Comment: Sure, you can use `INDEX()` to retrieve elements from your array, but it would get rid of the spilling behaviour and to me sounds like a shame. --> `=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($A2:$A10)),COLUMN(A1))` dragged right.

Comment: =INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A10)),COLUMN(A1)) dragged right.    i trried dragging this an its giving me a #REF error

Comment: @Girl007, see the difference with semi-absolute range references --> **$A2:$A10**, that should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips! I needed to do the opposite, with values in **horizontal row to unique values in a column**, which I solved with this:

```
= UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(K3:AL3))
```

With the unique values starting at AO4, I could then make sums for each unique value with the source values in row 3 and numbers to sum in row 4.

```
= SUMIFS($L$4:$AL$4; $L$3:$AL$3; AO4)
```

This way I could get a list like a pivot table, which requires *"headers, with a single row of unique, non-blank labels for each column"*, and since I had multiple equal values in the "header row", I don't think I could use an actual pivot table, but this worked fine too.